# How to get rid of unwanted tooltips in Excel 2013 addin ribbon

Tags: c#, ms-office, vsto

I have written an Excel VSTO Addin with C# that is compatible with Excel 2013 as well as Excel 2016/365.
In Excel 2013, I see a tooltip window for every ribbon button, that contains my addin's name and a link to more information, which simply opens a help topic about addins.
I don't want either. If I add a "`ScreenTip`" or a "`SuperTip`" to my ribbon buttons, they will be added on top of this unwanted tooltip, but they don't replace it.
Excel 2016 does not show such tooltips.
How can I get rid of them? I only want my own `ScreenTip`s and `SuperTip`s

[image: Excel 2013 unwanted tooltip]

Since I am using the VS Ribbon designer, I have no, and don't want to have, access to the underlying ribbon XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get rid of them, that part is controlled by Microsoft. Assumedly it was part of Microsoft's goal of helping to inform users that a control is not a Standard Office control, so that when it breaks, they don't blame MS for it, but instead recognize the identifier listed there and then seek support from whoever made the Add-In.

Comment: Thanks a lot,
In the meantime, I found the answer myself, here is a link to the MS forum that deals with the topic.[Link to forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/22ff2fbf-9d6f-490f-be3b-e92ef4bfb2d5/how-to-disable-the-popup-tooltip-on-ribbon-button?forum=vsto)

Interestingly, they abandoned this idea with Office 2016.